# java.util.logging does not exist bug?

Tags: java, logging, netbeans

I am trying to import java.util.logging into my class but it doesn't exist.
I am using Netbeans 8.2 installed just a few weeks ago, when I started learning Java and Netbeans.

I found this old bug report [Bugzilla report](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=35362) but this is so old, I would expect it to be fixed, especially for a logging function.

The following is the only code I have in the class file.  The 2 java.awt classes import OK. I added those just to prove that I had access to the standard Java library. The auto suggest does not suggest anything starting with log...

```
package myflag.flag.logging;

import java.util.logging;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
```

Any ideas please???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only a type can be imported. `java.util.logging` is a package. Please specify directly what class you need to import or you can import like this for all class inside this package: `import java.util.logging.*;`

Comment: SOLVED.  Your solution worked.  Thanks.  I just have to figure out how to figure out whether I am dealing with a package or a class so I don't repeat the same mistake.

Comment: Nice! Please accept my answer! or vote it up @dazz. Thanks